# "How to extract periodical data from a single column of the Pandas Dataframe"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file of Big Data with 161941 rows × 76 columns, out of which I have extracted the useful data with 161941 rows × 3 columns.

Now my dataframe Looks this way

[Extracted Dataframme of size 161941 rows × 3 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20BnC.jpg)

The column "bKLR_Touchauswertung" is periodical data and Looks in this form

```
"bKLR_Touchauswertung"
7
7
10
10
10
10
10
7
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
7
7
10
10
10
10
10
10
7
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
7
7
10
10
10
10
10
7
7
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

and it goes repeating till the end

What I would like to have from this is.

The each set of non Zeros values  from the column should be taken and appened as new columns to the dataframe.

lets say, the first set of nonzero values should taken as an new column "set1" and so on..

It would be great if I can get any possible solution.
Thanks,
Abhinay

---

Here is a more detailed example of the initial and expected dataframes:

This is my data Frame below

```
               temp     toucha
Timestamp      

**185            83         7
191            83         7
197            83         10
.              .          .
.              .          .
.              .          .
2051           83         10**

2057           83         0
2063           83         0
2057           83         0
.              .          .
.              .          .
.              .          .
3000           83         0

**3006           83         7
3012           83         7
3018           83         10
.              .          .
.              .          .
.              .          .
6000           83         10**

6006           83         0
6012           83         0
6018           83         0
.              .          .
.              .          .
.              .          .
8000           83         0
```

and this sequence goes on,

Now, I Need a dataframe which looks like this

```
                temp     toucha  set1   set2    ste3.............
Timestamp      

**185            83         7     7      0
191            83         7      7      0
197            83         10     10     0 
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      .
2051           83         10     10     0**

2057           83         0      0      0
2063           83         0      0      0
2057           83         0      0      0
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      .
3000           83         0      0      0

**3006           83         7     0      7
3012           83         7      0      7
3018           83         10     0      10
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      .
6000           83         10     0      10**

6006           83         0      0      0
6012           83         0      0      0
6018           83         0      0      0
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      .
.              .          .      .      . 
8000           83         0      0      0
```

Comment: Please give expected output in proper format and a minimum example of the input dataframe.

Comment: so for example all `7`s get a `set1`, all `10`s get a `set2`, is that what you mean?

Comment: my head aches... i just cant decode your question. Can you explain it a bit more? try to show what you want the output to be.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is by far not the worst I have seen from a new user, but this site has rules that you have failed to observe. So you really should read [ask] to know how to correctly ask question which will help in getting answers. Specifically here, you have no shown your current research, you have posted a link to an image, when you could have given test directly in the question and you have not described the expected result. You should try to improve this question (after having read [ask]...)

Comment: I wonder why my attachment is not being visible here, also I tried to edit the post and I could see the body of my question along with the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept that the numbers of the `setxx` columns are not necessarily consecutive, it is possible to use shift to detect changes between 0 and non 0 values and then `np.split` to split the dataframe indices on those changes.

Once this is done, it is simple to add a new column of 0 per sequence and copy the original values in it. But it is easier with a simply consecutive index because of `np.split`. So the code could be:

```
# use a simple consecutive index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# split the indices on transition between null and non null values
subs = np.split(df.index.values,
                df[((df.toucha == 0)&(df.toucha.shift() != 0)
                     |(df.toucha != 0)&(df.toucha.shift() == 0))
                    ].index.values)

# process those sequences
for i, a in enumerate(subs):
    # ignore empty or 0 value sequences
    if len(a) == 0: continue
    if df.toucha[a[0]] == 0: continue
    df['set'+str(i)] = 0    # initialize a new column with 0
    df.loc[a, 'set'+str(i)] = df.toucha.loc[a]  # and copy values

# set the index back
df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
```

With the following example data

```
           temp  toucha
Timestamp              
185          83       7
191          83       7
197          83      10
2051         83      10
2057         83       0
2063         83       0
2057         83       0
3000         83       0
3006         83       7
3012         83       7
3018         83      10
6000         83      10
6006         83       0
6012         83       0
6018         83       0
8000         83       0
```

it gives:

```
           temp  toucha  set0  set2
Timestamp                          
185          83       7     7     0
191          83       7     7     0
197          83      10    10     0
2051         83      10    10     0
2057         83       0     0     0
2063         83       0     0     0
2057         83       0     0     0
3000         83       0     0     0
3006         83       7     0     7
3012         83       7     0     7
3018         83      10     0    10
6000         83      10     0    10
6006         83       0     0     0
6012         83       0     0     0
6018         83       0     0     0
8000         83       0     0     0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and really appreciate your help. I almost have the final solution what I wanted.

Comment: @Abhinayb: I could read you now deleted *edit in answer* and update my answer with it

Answer (score 0):

```
# use a simple consecutive index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# split the indices on transition between null and non null values
subs = np.split(df.index.values,
            df[((df.toucha == 0)&(df.toucha.shift() != 0)
                 |(df.toucha != 0)&(df.toucha.shift() == 0))
                ].index.values)

# process those sequences
for i, a in enumerate(subs):
    # ignore empty or 0 value sequences
    if len(a) == 0: continue
    if df.toucha[a[0]] == 0: continue
    df['set'+str(i)] = 0    # initialize a new column with 0
    df.loc[a, 'set'+str(i)] = df.toucha.loc[a]  # and copy values

# set the index back
df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)
```